# TS2339: Property 'join' does not exist on type after making sure it is an array

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have multiple types acceptable as a value in an object and one of them is array. When I get an array as parameter, I want to override it as a comma separated list. Apparently, after making sure the element I am trying to convert is indeed an array, Typescript returns a type related error:

```
for (const key in parameters) {
      if (Array.isArray(parameters[key])) {
        parameters[key] = parameters[key].join(',');
      }                                   ^^^^
                                         TS2339: Property 'join' does not exist on type
```

`parameters` type definition looks like this: `parameters: Record<string, string | boolean | number | Array<string>`

How can I get it to realize that the parameter is indeed an array in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use another variable:

```
let parameters : Record<string, string | boolean | number | Array<string>> =
{
    's' : 1
}

for (const key in parameters) {
    let ass = parameters[key];
      if (Array.isArray(ass)) {
        parameters[key] = ass.join(',');
      }   
}
```

[Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/DYUwLgBADghgTjAtuEcDOEBcEBKIDGA9nACYA8aYcAlgHYDmANBJTQxAD4QBGhhoMWpwi0Arom6phAQTgIAnhSp16APlUQAvAFgAUAG89EYxADkaU1ggBGPQF89egGbEIACiK1KEANYh5EHTQ8Ego6ACUEIa6JhCgkDBoGJrBCMhgqGgA2n7yALoA3EaxgU7usgoAdNRoFTDybolo4ZHRJSawaWHZuXlaEE2VAFaEdG6mjKbhRTEldib2QA)

Comment: This works but can you explain why? Seems redundant to create a new variable when it's literally mirroring the value you're checking already, almost feel like it's unintentional and an overlook